# How to control CL acquisition by DM scripting?

Tags: hardware, dm-script

We have a trasmission electron microscope equipped with a cathode luminescence (CL) spectrometer, Gatan Vulcan TEM-CL system. I would like to acquire many CL spectra sequentially while changing the spectral wavelength range step by step, by using Gatan  DigitalMicrograph scripting. Are there scripting commands for a CL spectrum acquisition and controlling the wavelength range? In EELS and EDS cases, there are "EELSAcquireSpectrum()" and "EDSSAcquireSpectrum()", respectively. Is there similar command for CL? Especially, the control command for wavelength range is a important one for our objectives.

It will be approciated if you could share some wisdom. Thank you very much in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The F1 online help does not seem to contain a documentation in the current version, but on hardware-installtion you likely have received addtional (printed) documentation. I have found the following script commands in the printed manual for the **MonoCL4 System** (see below).

[image]

> There is a specific *disclaimer* in that section which states that Gatan does not provide any support or guarantees with the commands.

---

### page 93 (Section 12.4)

[image]

Comment: I sincerely appreciate your swift response. These commands worked quite well. I'm going to try using these commands immediately.